# Using os.open() and .read() on a named pipe in python2.7 results in AttributeError

Tags: python-2.7, named-pipes, fifo, attributeerror

I'm using Python2.7 and my operating system is Ubuntu14.04.

In my python code I'm using `fifo = os.open('fifo', os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDONLY)` to open a named pipe. I then use `string = fifo.read(7)` to read seven characters from that pipe. Before running the code I create the pipe in the command line with `mkfifo fifo`. When I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    string = fifo.read(7)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

*More details if needed:*
I'm using the fifo to pipe the output of an answer-set-programming (ASP) file into a string in my python code. The python file's output is being piped to the input of the ASP file (running in query mode). So, python sends a query to ASP, response is put into the fifo pipe, python reads that response into a string.

The reason I'm using O_NONBLOCK is that execution was stalling without it, though I don't know why as I'm pretty sure the ASP file was writing to the fifo; I tested a similar method using a text file instead of a fifo, and the ASP output was definitely going into the text file.

I'm running my code with the command `python pythonfile.py | java -jar sparc.jar aspfile.sp > fifo`.

Please notify me in a comment if you need more information and I will post my code. Thank you for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.open` corresponds to the underlying C library's `open(3)` call. It returns a file descriptor which is just an integer index (corresponding C type is `int`).

To use the file descriptor, just use `os.write`/`os.read`, or wrap it in a file object by `os.fdopen`.  You cannot call the `read` method *on* it, because a file descriptor is just a Python integer and there's no `read` method on an integer.

References: Python library reference for `os`, and Unix C man pages in section 3.

P.S. To create a named pipe, just use `os.mkfifo`.  No need to fork an external command. The `os` module wraps most of the POSIX I/O functions.